# What is 建设 in ...以期更好地展现我国航天建设的辉煌成就...?

Tags: meaning

This is from an interview with 航天员杨利伟。

> 今天的访谈我想和他聊聊他的这段奇妙的太空经历，以期更好地展现我国航天建设的辉煌成就，....

建设 normally means 'build'. Do you 'build or construct (建设） accomplishments （成就）' in Chinese?

'我国航天建设的辉煌成就'  'China's space flight project's glorious accomplishments'

I think I could replace this 建设 with 项目 here, so I have 'space flight (航天） project （建设， 项目）。

Does this use of 建设 here seem strange at all?

Comment: It means 事业或活动, enterprise, project or activity.

Comment: = program / plan & implementations thereof.

Answer (score 2):

In mainland China, 建设 can have the meaning of "cause", similar to 事业. It is often said that

> 在社会主义**建设**的道路上…
>   On the road of the construction (cause) of the socialism society...

From [a random online dictionary](http://zh.thefreedictionary.com/%E5%BB%BA%E8%AE%BE) from Google:

> 建设 — **创建新事业**或增加新设施
>   (**Construct new causes** or add new equipments)

So in your case, 我国航天建设 is an elliptical phrase, where 事业 is omitted, which should look like

> 我国航天事业的建设
>   The construction of our cause for spaceflight

In practice, you can translate 建设 into "cause" or "the construction of xxx project" (我国航天工程) depending on the context.

Comment: Did you miss something in the quotes in the first sentence?

Comment: @fefe My bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

建设 is a noun word here, and can be interpreted as "construction". Like 中国建设银行 is translated to China Construction Bank. 项目 is not the same as 建设 here. 航天建设 would involve many projects.